Resolve Insecure Direct Object Reference in ASP.NET Core Web API
Our application has an Insecure Direct Object Reference vulnerability, or IDOR. Basically there are object IDs displayed in the url. I would like to know what would be the most efficient approach to resolve this vulnerability. Our frontend is built in Angular 16, and our backend in .NET Core.
I thought of encrypting the object IDs using a 'salt key', then decrypt it back when necessary. At the same time, I would like to know what would be the best algorithm for this.

The question of "what would I do" can't be answered with so little context. "ID's", in general, should be nonsense numbers to start with.

Correct, but those numbers mean something in the database. A potential attacker can edit these numbers and access objects they are not entitled to see
